# How the Get action method is getting called in Docusign API example

Tags: docusignapi

This is a newbie question about the DocuSign API. I just downloaded the C# example. Excellent flow, which demonstrates the API capabilities. But I do not understand how the Get() action method is getting called in eSignature\Controllers\EgControllers. I do not see any route to the Get() action method and the default routes defined in Startup.cs point to an Index action method, not Get. Shouldn't the Get() action method be named Index()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you downloaded a C# [Quickstart](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/quickstart/) that include a lot of calls built using the C# SDKs.
The C# [eSignature SDK](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/sdk-tools/) is making all calls for you, including the GETs.
When you use an SDK, it's a wrapper that handles the calls for you, so you don't have to worry about GET or POST or JSON.

For example, this line in the C# code you have (eSignature/Examples/GetEnvelopeInformations) is making a GET call inside the SDK:

```
        return envelopesApi.GetEnvelope(accountId, envelopeId);
```

Comment: Thanks very much. Very useful. Indeed, I am trying to understand the C# QuickStart.

Comment: I see that when I run the launcher-csharp app, the first call is to eSignatures/Controllers/HomeController/Index(). This method redirects to "eg001". This leads to the LocalsFilter/OnActionExecuting() and immediately thereafter, the EgController/Get() action method is called. There is no SDK method invoked so far that I can see. How did we get to EgController/Get()?

Comment: These are just all part of the C# MVC app for the UI of our app which we call "Launcher".

Comment: The first DocuSign eSign API call is only made after you :
1. Consent to the app (one time)
2. Click the button on the first page with your email and name. Then it will go to make 2 API calls for you (both are POST, not GET)